# Installing Puppeteer NodeJS module on Stremio BeamUp servers

Tags: puppeteer, buildpack

I haven't got any experience with Platform As A Services and I have difficulties with the installation and configuration of the right buildpack. More specifically I don't know how to configure Streamio BeamUp servers to run Puppeteer library.

I'll try to summarize everything and if needed I'll provide more details.

1. I build a Stremio addon that relies on [stremio-addon-sdk](https://github.com/Stremio/stremio-addon-sdk), NodeJs, [Puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer) and other modules.
2. The addon works fine when installed locally.
3. I managed to successfully deploy the addon on Stremio BeamUp servers following [the official guide](https://github.com/Stremio/stremio-addon-sdk/blob/master/docs/deploying/beamup.md).
4. The addon successfully installs in Stremio.
5. The issue occurs when I'm trying to use the addon, I got the following error message in the log:

> Error: Could not find Chrome (ver. 122.0.6261.57). This can occur if
> either 1. you did
> not perform an installation before running the script (e.g. `npx puppeteer browsers install chrome`) or |  2. your
> cache path is incorrectly configured (which is:
> /app/.cache/puppeteer).

6. I did my research and found out that Puppeteer library requires additional configuration based on the respective server. According to BeamUp github page BeamUp is based on [Doku/Heroku](https://github.com/Stremio/stremio-beamup) and it support buildpack.
7. I found a [this guide](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#running-puppeteer-on-heroku) for installing a buildpack that support Puppeteer Heroku platform.
8. I tried [building .buildpacks](https://dokku.com/docs%7Ev0.5.8/deployment/buildpacks/#using-multiple-buildpacks) file with link to the [respective buildpack](https://github.com/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack) but I failed.
9. Now I'm trying to to the same thing with a .docker file but again I'm lost.

BeamUp documentation is very limited and even though Puppeteer and Heroku docs are very detailed I can't find the answer on my own. Any guidance would be much appreciated.